# Building a "pixel perfect" AND responsive web design from PSD?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, psd

Okay so I am in a dilemma an need advice from professionals.

Beginner at web design.

- When converting PSDs to html/css I am using exact padding ratios from
  (px to rem) the PSD mockup.
- Looks great in the `320px` width document (as per mockup specs).
- Setting a base font-size for different screen sizes in `html` tag
  i.e. `320px` width has a `10px` font-size, `12px` at `399px` screen size,
  etc. *Font-size is in rem so everything is relative to base font.*
  Again, seems responsive.

**Here is the problem**

Since everything padding and width is exact portions relative to initial 320px (initial mockup document), I have to have to many break points and have to increase html font size too frequently so the portions are the same relative to new screen size.

It a little excessive and seems like the wrong approach. What is the standard approach to having the "pixel perfect" proportions without having excessive breakpoints?

Potential solutions I'm considering

- Use proportions from psd mockup for padding/margins and keep the
  width fluid i.e. use `text-align: center` instead of giving exact
  width i.e. `width: Xrem;` (as I have to increase width excessively
  for greater breakpoints.

**Requirement:** Create a pixel perfect web design from PSDs (as realistic as possible) and be responsive without have to back excessive breakpoints.

What is the standard approach, what should be exact ratios e.x margin/padding and what should be fluid e.x width?

***EDIT: Made a JS Snippet below but doesn't display different breakpoints.***

***Here is an example (Consider the blue div, that is .sec-1 which is pixel perfect to PSD MOCKUP (320px)***

html

```
        <div class="sec-1">
        <div class="col-1">
            <h1>Introducing 'Keeva' world's smartest assistant.</h1>
            <h2>Keeva smartphone app helps you organize your work schedule, meetings, project deadlines and much more.</h2> 
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
        <!-- Download Buttons -->
            <div class="download-wrap">
            <!--  playstore icon -->
                <picture>
              <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="http://via.placeholder.com/97x31">
<!--                          <source media="(min-width: 465px)" srcset="img_white_flower.jpg">
-->                       <img class="download-btns" src="img_orange_flowers.jpg" alt="Flowers" style="width:auto;">
            </picture>
            <!--  appstore icon -->
                <picture>
              <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="http://via.placeholder.com/97x31">
<!--                          <source media="(min-width: 465px)" srcset="img_white_flower.jpg">
-->                       <img class="download-btns" src="img_orange_flowers.jpg" alt="Flowers" style="width:auto;">
            </picture>
            </div>  

                <!-- iphone 1 image wrap -->
            <div class="hero-img">
            <!--  iphone image -->
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="http://via.placeholder.com/142x142">
        <!--                          <source media="(min-width: 465px)" srcset="img_white_flower.jpg">
        -->                       <img class="phone-img" src="img_orange_flowers.jpg" alt="Flowers" style="width:auto;">
                </picture>
            </div>

        </div>
```

CSS

```css
/* BASIC ELEMENTS */
* {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
html {
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-size: 10px;
}

h1 {
 font-size: 2rem;
 text-align: center;

}
h2, h3 {
 font-size: 1.6rem;
 font-weight: normal;
 text-align: center;
}

h3 {
 font-weight: bold;
}

h4{
 font-size: 1.5rem;
 font-weight: normal;
 text-align: center;
}

/* SECTION ONE */
.sec-1 {
 background-color: #2094d0;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 text-align: center;

}


.col-1 h1 {
 padding-top: 15px;
 padding-left: 4.3rem;
 width: 23.8rem; 
 text-align: center;
 }

 .col-1 h2 {
  padding-top: 2.7rem;
  padding-bottom: 1.1rem;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  width: 29.9rem;
 }

.col-2 {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 align-items: center;
}

/* HERO IPHONE IMAGE */
.phone-img {
 padding-right: 1rem;
 margin-bottom: -3px;
}
/* DOWNLOAD BTNS */
.download-wrap {
 padding: 1rem;

}

/* SECTION THREE */
.sec-3 {
 background-color: #f1eeee;
}


/*  MEDIA QUERIES */
@media(min-width: 399px) {
 html {
  font-size: 12px;
  }

}
```

```html
  <div class="sec-1">
   <div class="col-1">
      <h1>Introducing 'Keeva' world's smartest assistant.</h1>
      <h2>Keeva smartphone app helps you organize your work schedule, meetings, project deadlines and much more.</h2> 
   </div>
   <div class="col-2">
   <!-- Download Buttons -->
    <div class="download-wrap">
    <!--  playstore icon -->
     <picture>
      <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="http://via.placeholder.com/97x31">
 <!--         <source media="(min-width: 465px)" srcset="img_white_flower.jpg">
 -->        <img class="download-btns" src="img_orange_flowers.jpg" alt="Flowers" style="width:auto;">
    </picture>
    <!--  appstore icon -->
     <picture>
      <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="http://via.placeholder.com/97x31">
 <!--         <source media="(min-width: 465px)" srcset="img_white_flower.jpg">
 -->        <img class="download-btns" src="img_orange_flowers.jpg" alt="Flowers" style="width:auto;">
    </picture>
    </div> 

     <!-- iphone 1 image wrap -->
    <div class="hero-img">
      <!--  iphone image -->
     <picture>
        <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="http://via.placeholder.com/142x142">
   <!--         <source media="(min-width: 465px)" srcset="img_white_flower.jpg">
   -->        <img class="phone-img" src="img_orange_flowers.jpg" alt="Flowers" style="width:auto;">
     </picture>
    </div>
    
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing is when we do PSD to HTML first need to check all the grid structure that designer made by him/her is that correct or not by addition of each and every points like column, borders etc.

1. Check base layout of psd
2. If designer gives designs for basic resolution for tablet and mobile then it is well and good. If not then ask him/her how it should be in mobile as well as tablet.
3. If you don't want put lots of media query then you can refer [this link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

Answer (score 0):

Don't waste time having pixel perfect, it doesn't exist. Focus on details and responsive part and UX. AVOID all those marketing, sales or even dodgy CEO asking for pixel perfect implementation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).